# With leftOuterJoin, .DefaultIfEmpty() is unnecessary

Tags: f#, query-expressions

The documentation for `leftOuterJoin` [Query Expressions on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx) repeatedly implies through the samples that when using `leftOuterJoin .. on .. into ..` that you must still use `.DefaultIfEmpty()` to achieve the desired effect.

I don't believe this is necessary because I get the same results in both of these tests which differ only in that the second one does not `.DefaultIfEpmty()`

```
type Test = A | B | C
let G = [| A; B; C|]
let H = [| A; C; C|]

printfn "%A" <| query {
    for g in G do
    leftOuterJoin h in H on (g = h) into I
    for i in I.DefaultIfEmpty() do 
    select (g, i)}

printfn "%A" <| query {
    for g in G do
    leftOuterJoin h in H on (g = h) into I
    for i in I do 
    select (g, i)}

// seq [(A, A); (B, null); (C, C); (C, C)]
// seq [(A, A); (B, null); (C, C); (C, C)]
```

1) Can you confirm this?

If that's right, I realized it only after writing this alternate type augmentation in an attempt to better deal with unmatched results and I was surprised to still see `null`s in my output!

```
type IEnumerable<'TSource> with
    member this.NoneIfEmpty = if (Seq.exists (fun _ -> true) this) 
                              then Seq.map (fun e -> Some e) this 
                              else seq [ None ]

printfn "%A" <| query {
    for g in G do
    leftOuterJoin h in H on (g = h) into I
    for i in I.NoneIfEmpty do 
    select (g, i)}

// seq [(A, Some A); (B, Some null); (C, Some C); (C, Some C)]
```

2) Is there a way to get `None` instead of `null`/`Some null` from the `leftOuterJoin`?

3) What I really want to do is find out if there are any unmatched `g`

```
printfn "%A" <| query {
    for g in G do
    leftOuterJoin h in H on (g = h) into I
    for i in I.NoneIfEmpty do
    where (i.IsNone)
    exists (true) }
```

I figured this next one out but it isn't very F#:

```
printfn "%A" <| query {
    for g in G do
    leftOuterJoin h in H on (g = h) into I
    for i in I do
    where (box i = null) 
    exists (true)}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: Query Expressions use nulls. It's a rough spot in the language, but a containable one.

I've done this before:

```ml
let ToOption (a:'a) =
    match obj.ReferenceEquals(a,null) with
    | true -> None
    | false -> Some(a)
```

This will let you do:

```
printfn "%A" <| query {
    for g in G do
    leftOuterJoin h in H on (g = h) into I
    for i in I do 
    select ( g,(ToOption i))}
```

Which wraps every result in an option (since you don't know if there is going to be an I. It's worth noting that F# uses `null` to represent None at run-time as an optimization. So to check if this is indeed what you want, make a decision on the option, like:

```
Seq.iter (fun (g,h) -> 
              printf "%A," g; 
              match h with 
              | Some(h) -> printfn "Some (%A)" h 
              | None -> printfn "None")  
    <| query {
    for g in G do
    leftOuterJoin h in H on (g = h) into I
    for i in I do 
    select ((ToOption g),(ToOption i))}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  And so back to 1) is the documentation truly flawed?  I'd put in for it.

Comment: Hmm... what do you think should be the behavior?

Comment: After doing a bit of research into [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.110).aspx), it does nothing since `I` is flattened.

Comment: Yeah, in all cases, right?  I mean, the C# LINQ way to do a left join is with a `join .. into .. from ...DefaultIfEmtpy()` so I would think that the only reason to have both a `join` and a `leftOuterJoin` keyword here is so you don't have to both with that nonsense.  And regardless of the provider, I would think that an empty set is an empty set.  I don't know what could change about the provider that would affect this (not that I'm qualified to recognize it).