# leftOuterJoin and `.DefaultIfEmpty()` queries in F#

Tags: f#

I have a relatively simple `F#` query expression with a join:

```
let mdrQuery = 
    query {
        for header in db.CustomerDetails do
        leftOuterJoin row in db.MDR_0916
            on (header.PID = row.PID) into result
        select (result, header)
        }
```

This returns every `header` and `result` but for a `header` that has not match in `row`, `result` is just an empty sequence and, when the query results are passed to a custom Type, I get an error that a constructor associated with a field in `row` is not defined.  This makes sense as for any `header` that has no match in `row`, a `null` sequence is returned.  An example:

```
mdrQuery |> Seq.head;;
val it :
  seq<dbSchema.ServiceTypes.MDR_0916> * dbSchema.ServiceTypes.CustomerDetails
= (seq [null], CustomerDetails {ACCOUNTMANAGER = null;
                            ACCOUNTSTATUS = "XC";
                            ADDRESSLINE1 = null;
                            ADDRESSLINE2 = null;
                            ADDRESSLINE3 = null;
                            ADDRESSLINE4 = "123 PIG ROAD"...
```

I suspect that there's a way around this because of [the `leftOuterJoin` documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/query-expressions).  But, when I try using that example as a template for *my* query:

```
let mdrQuery = 
    query {
        for header in db.CustomerDetails do
        leftOuterJoin row in db.MDR_0916
            on (header.PID = row.PID) into result
        for row in result.DefaultIfEmpty() do
        select (result, header)
        }
```

the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` piece errors out with

```
error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'DefaultIfEmpty' is not defined
```

Is there a way that I can make this join happen *and* select every row, filling the unmatched rows in `result` with `None` (or some other null SQL null value) so that the entirety of the query can be passed to my record type?

Ideally, the output for an unmatched row would be something like (truncated results created by hand below)

```
mdrQuery |> Seq.head;;
val it :
  seq<dbSchema.ServiceTypes.MDR_0916> * dbSchema.ServiceTypes.CustomerDetails
= (MDR_0916 {AIMExp = null;
         AP = null;
         APComp = null;
         APEng = null;
         APFine = null;
         APForl = null;...}, 
CustomerDetails {ACCOUNTMANAGER = null;
                            ACCOUNTSTATUS = "XC";
                            ADDRESSLINE1 = null;
                            ADDRESSLINE2 = null;
                            ADDRESSLINE3 = null;
                            ADDRESSLINE4 = "123 PIG ROAD"...
```

**Edit:** [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008069/with-leftouterjoin-defaultifempty-is-unnecessary) is similar to mine but including `ToOption result` simply outputs a `Some (seq [null])`.

Comment: In your interactive output, `result` is not an empty sequence, but rather a sequence of one element, and that element is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` is an extension method, so you need to `open System.Linq`.

Comment: Opening `System.Linq` clears the error but doesn't affect anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is wrong; in C# there is no direct equivalent of a `leftOuterJoin` operator, so `DefaultIfEmpty` is used with a normal join, but in F# you don't need this (the query builder performs this translation for you - see `QueryBuilder.LeftOuterJoin` in the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/Query.fs) if you're curious).

If you want the results of a traditional left join, then just add the additional `for` loop *without* `DefaultIfEmpty` (but note - you want to select the newly bound `row` value, *not* the `result` sequence):

```
let mdrQuery = 
    query {
        for header in db.CustomerDetails do
        leftOuterJoin row in db.MDR_0916
            on (header.PID = row.PID) into result
        for row in result do
        select (row, header)
    }
```

Note that this will give you `null` values for `MDR_0916` entries that were missing, not special `MDR_0916` values with `null` field values, though, so you might want to apply a post-processing step if you need the latter.

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the suggestion of applying a post processing step to create the `MDR_0916` values with `null` field values.  I ended up selecting only those fields from `MDR...` that I needed and rewrote how I passed it to a custom type.